# How to filter nodes in gojs in the UI?

Tags: gojs

I am working on an org chart with go.js.

One thing I am not able to figure out is, how do I filter on particular nodes? Is it possible to have a UI for searching nodes in go.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a search box in the [org chart static sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html) that gives an example of filtering nodes.

```
// create a case insensitive RegExp from what the user typed
var regex = new RegExp(input.value, "i");

...

// search four different data properties for the string, any of which may match for success
var results = myDiagram.findNodesByExample({ name: regex },
                                           { nation: regex },
                                           { title: regex },
                                           { headOf: regex });
```

See the documentation for [findNodesByExample](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#findNodesByExample) for more information.

Comment: Great! that does the trick. I completely overlooked the search field in this example. Thanks.